# odoo 10 Access Denied while printing XLSX report

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, xlsxwriter

while trying to generate an .xlsx report using `InvoiceReportXls` class and `generate_xlsx_report` method I got a weard error `Access denied`

to let you know, on my local VM everything work perfectly, but when I upload my code on another VM, which seems to has the same configuration as mine I got the error below.

> File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 506, in check
>     raise AccessDenied()
>     AccessDenied: Access denied

**sql_export.py**

```
@api.multi
def execute_query(self):
    datas['form'] = self.read()[0]
    name = 'Export OR'+ ' ' + date
    return {'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
            'report_name': 'my_module.my_report_name.xlsx',
            'datas': datas,
            'name': name
            }
```

**report_export.py**

```
from odoo.addons.report_xlsx.report.report_xlsx import ReportXlsx
class InvoiceReportXls(ReportXlsx):
    def execute_query(self,datas):
        query = '''
            SELECT ... from ... 
            '''
        self.env.cr.execute(query,(...,...,),)
        lines = []
        lines = self.env.cr.dictfetchall()
        return lines

     def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, lines):
         sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('field_')
         #my_xlsx_code ...
InvoiceReportXls('report.my_module.my_report_name.xlsx','account.invoice')
```

**view.xml**

```
    <report
        id="export_invoice_xlsx"
        model="account.invoice"
        string=" "
        report_type="xlsx"
        name="my_module.my_report_name.xlsx"
        file="my_module.my_report_name.xlsx"
        attachment_use="False"
    />
```